# the second pop up run behind the first ( ng prime )

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a **ng prime modal** where I am showing my data so when I want to delete one of my data by clicking in a button to display a second popup,  the second popup appears behind the first like exemples in the photos :
**ps**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiEvb.png)

**HTML COde**

```
    <table>
      <tr>

                    <td>
                      <p-button
                        (onClick)="confirm($event)"
                        icon="pi pi-trash"
                        label="Clear"
                      ></p-button>
                      <p-confirmPopup></p-confirmPopup>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: you need to update your CSS so that the second overlay is displayed above the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css of your p-confirmPopup component, you should set your z-index greather than first component.